# Do I need to create a new account for all stackexchange sites?

Tags: discussion

I want to post some questions to stackexchange/webapps. I was requested to create a new account, which I did with the same email address I use for blender stack exchange. Do I need to create a new account for each StackExchange site? Seems a little bit cumbersome to me.

Answer (score 3):

No need to create a new account. While logged in, go to the site you want to join, and click *Join This Community*  [image]. You will also receive an [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus-and-how-does-it-work) of 101 reputation points.

Comment: Ok but i was requested to set a new password and i could choose a different user name. But it’s definitely the same email address. I dont get it…